# Atom no auto reload on save using npm live-server

Tags: npm, sass, atom-editor

I want to use `npm live-server` with the *Atom* text editor.
I'm also using a script to watch for sass changes and compile it to CSS.
Normally, when I make a change in any `.scss` file, it gets compiled and refreshed and I see the changes in the browser, but in *Atom*, the changes won't take effect unless I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on the `main.scss` file again.

I've tried sublime text and brackets and everything works fine.
It's just *Atom* that has this problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not have auto save on loose focus, but you can use plugins for it like this one: https://atom.io/packages/autosave